# Подниматься В гору или НА гору — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

*Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору,

Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.

Гляжу, **поднимается** медленно **в гору**

Лошадка, везущая хворосту воз.*
Н. А. Некрасов. Крестьянские дети

*Мотоциклист начинает **подниматься на гору** с начальной скоростью 36 км/ч и останавливается на вершине горы* (из задачи по физике).

*В данном материале мы рассмотрим такой важный момент для подобных путешествий, как умение правильно **подниматься на гору**, а также, как правильно с нее спускаться* (из статьи о вождении а/м).

А как правильно? Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Дополнение - уточнение.  Я имела ввиду "подниматься" - передвигаться,  перемещаться наверх.   Ведь ни мотоциклист,  ни автомобилист не карабкаются, не цепляются,  не восходят.

Answer (score 3):

"**В гору**" (как в первом примере) обозначает направление движения *вверх по наклонной поверхности*; противоположное направление движения - "**под уклон**" (так чаще говорят о дороге, которая по мере движения по ней вдруг пошла наклонно вниз, но говорят так и о наблюдаемом движении поезда и т. п.). Оба выражения (формально их относят к устойчивым *наречным сочетаниям*) могут употребляться и в более абстрактном смысле (о течении жизни, карьеры и пр.). *Лошадка* двигалась в направлении подъёма дороги. Подобным же образом говорят о движении *по течению* или *против течения* реки (в одном из этих направлений двигаться труднее).

"**На гору**" (второй и третий примеры) употреблено в контексте упоминания о имеющейся **горе**, и здесь **на** - обычный предлог в сочетании с существительным; смысл - *буквальный*.

Comment: Вы реально полагаете, учебная статья о вождении автомашины может рассказывать об умении подниматься на буквально понимаемую "гору"? Я согласен, что по значению слова понимать надо именно так, но в этом-то и состоит ошибка автора.

Comment: Если в том же предложении на гору сослались местоимением, то явно имеют в виду гору. Не видел всей статьи (возможно, там не об элементарном вождении), но такое реально. Сам когда-то заезжал на крымскую гору Ай-Петри на такси.

Answer (score 2):

У Некрасова (и вообще "в гору") означает "вверх", "на подъем", здесь сохраняется архаичный в русском смысл слова "гора". Горы как таковой там может и не быть, максимум — холм, возвышенность. Используется, как это следует из смысла, в функции наречия. Антоним — "под уклон".

А вот в задачнике какой-то не совсем адекватный мотоциклист или спортсмен-маунтинбайкер явно задался целью подняться на реальную гору. У неё даже вершина есть. Нормальные же мотоциклисты обычно едут только в гору, то есть по дороге,  ведущей наверх.

Что же касается статьи, то там, скорее всего, — лексическая ошибка. Хотя контекста недостаточно, но вряд ли в статье излагается подъем машины на реальную гору — вслед за условным мотоциклистом из задачи.

Comment: У вас, г-н @Morkovkin, "гора" – это всегда что-то типа Эвереста? На худой конец, пика Ленина?

Comment: @Niemand без комментариев

Answer (score 0):

"В гору" - Устойчивое сочетание (наречие). Используется в качестве наречной группы. Смысл: вверх ([Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83)))

"На гору" - речь идет о горе.