# Спуститься с горы и в неё подняться

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать *спуститься **с** горы и **в** неё подняться?*

Comment: С базовыми знаками пунктуации знакомы?

Answer (score 2):

В толковом словаре Ожегова:
**спуститься,** спущусь, спустишься; сов.
**1. с чего.** Переместиться сверху вниз. **Спуститься с горы.** Спуститься вниз по течению. Спуститься с облаков (перен.: от мечтаний обратиться к действительности; ирон.).

*В Анапе спасатели помогли женщине спуститься с горы.*

[подниматься](https://all_words.academic.ru/65661/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), поднимаюсь, поднимаешься; нсв.
2. Располагаться, простираться в направлении снизу вверх.
**Дорога поднимается в гору.**

*Машина поднималась в гору, выбрасывая из-под колес мелкие камешки и похрустывая по ледяным лужицам* (А. О. Авдеенко).

Некоторые особенности здесь:
[Подниматься В гору или НА гору — как правильно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430752/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%92-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9D%D0%90-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, стилистически такого лучше избегать. Просто могут не понять.

Как править - не могу сказать однозначно, сильно зависит от смысла. 
Конечно, "и подняться на гору" - первое, что приходит на ум, но это совсем небесспорный вариант, предлоги С и НА в таком контексте не являются точными антонимами.

Дело, конечно, не в предлогах как таковых, а в том, что "подниматься в гору" совсем не означает подниматься **на какую-то (конкретную) возвышенность**. "Спуститься с горы" - это да, это именно с горы, вернее всего - с вершины. Ну, может быть, какого-то холма.  А "в гору" - это просто дорога идет на подъем, там никакой горы может и не быть, тем более - вершины. А антоним тут - "под гору".

Если имеется в виду именно этот случай, надо так и писать.

Или еще вариант, с горки - на горку. Тут диссонанса и недоразумений будет меньше.

А вообще - посмотрите еще по ссылке у Риммы Михайловой, не буду её дублировать.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, можно, но это не есть хороший русский язык. Все-таки рядом с предлогом С хотелось бы НА.

Далее. Дорога может подниматься в гору, но человек обычно поднимается на гору. Однако может идти в гору.